# How can I organize my dataframe with a header like this?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

My program returns me a dictionary that has several layers. Drawing in Excel, it looks like this:

**Excel Template:**
[image: Excel Template]

The code returns this dictionary (it is already organized to help you visualize):

```
{'Parity': 'BITCOIN / TETHERUS', '1m': {'Datas': {'Price': {'Initial Price': '58239.43', 'Final Price': '58236.50'}, 'Oscillators': {'Buy': 1, 'Neutral': 8, 'Sell': 2}, 'MovingAverages': {'Buy': 6, 'Neutral': 1, 'Sell': 8}}}, '5m': {'Datas': {'Price': {'Initial Price': '58239.43', 'Final Price': '58231.56'}, 'Oscillators': {'Buy': 0, 'Neutral': 9, 'Sell': 2}, 'MovingAverages': {'Buy': 13, 'Neutral': 1, 'Sell': 1}}}, '15m': {'Datas': {'Price': {'Initial Price': '58239.43', 'Final Price': '58231.56'}, 'Oscillators': {'Buy': 1, 'Neutral': 6, 'Sell': 4}, 'MovingAverages': {'Buy': 13, 'Neutral': 1, 'Sell': 1}}}, '1h': {'Datas': {'Price': {'Initial Price': '58239.43', 'Final Price': '58231.55'}, 'Oscillators': {'Buy': 2, 'Neutral': 7, 'Sell': 2}, 'MovingAverages': {'Buy': 14, 'Neutral': 1, 'Sell': 0}}}, '4h': {'Datas': {'Price': {'Initial Price': '58239.43', 'Final Price':'58231.56'}, 'Oscillators': {'Buy': 3, 'Neutral': 8, 'Sell': 0}, 'MovingAverages': {'Buy': 14, 'Neutral': 1, 'Sell': 0}}}, '1D': {'Datas': {'Price': {'Initial Price': '58239.43', 'Final Price': '58231.56'}, 'Oscillators': {'Buy': 2, 'Neutra
l': 9, 'Sell': 0}, 'MovingAverages': {'Buy': 14, 'Neutral': 1, 'Sell': 0}}}, '1W': {'Datas': {'Price': {'Initial Price': '58239.43', 'Final Price': '58230.02'}, 'Oscillators': {'Buy': 1, 'Neutral': 9, 'Sell': 1}, 'MovingAverages': {'Buy': 12, 'Neutral': 3, 'Sell': 0}}}}
```

I would like to keep a dataframe in `xlsx` file organized like the one above.

Comment: see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

just two steps

1. `pd.json_normalize()` to generate a dataframe from the JSON
2. re-structure columns from dotted notation to multi-index using `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples()`

```
js = {"Parity": "BITCOIN / TETHERUS", "1m": {"Datas": {"Price": {"Initial Price": "58239.43", "Final Price": "58236.50"}, "Oscillators": {"Buy": 1, "Neutral": 8, "Sell": 2}, "MovingAverages": {"Buy": 6, "Neutral": 1, "Sell": 8}}}, "5m": {"Datas": {"Price": {"Initial Price": "58239.43", "Final Price": "58231.56"}, "Oscillators": {"Buy": 0, "Neutral": 9, "Sell": 2}, "MovingAverages": {"Buy": 13, "Neutral": 1, "Sell": 1}}}, "15m": {"Datas": {"Price": {"Initial Price": "58239.43", "Final Price": "58231.56"}, "Oscillators": {"Buy": 1, "Neutral": 6, "Sell": 4}, "MovingAverages": {"Buy": 13, "Neutral": 1, "Sell": 1}}}, "1h": {"Datas": {"Price": {"Initial Price": "58239.43", "Final Price": "58231.55"}, "Oscillators": {"Buy": 2, "Neutral": 7, "Sell": 2}, "MovingAverages": {"Buy": 14, "Neutral": 1, "Sell": 0}}}, "4h": {"Datas": {"Price": {"Initial Price": "58239.43", "Final Price": "58231.56"}, "Oscillators": {"Buy": 3, "Neutral": 8, "Sell": 0}, "MovingAverages": {"Buy": 14, "Neutral": 1, "Sell": 0}}}, "1D": {"Datas": {"Price": {"Initial Price": "58239.43", "Final Price": "58231.56"}, "Oscillators": {"Buy": 2, "Neutral": 9, "Sell": 0}, "MovingAverages": {"Buy": 14, "Neutral": 1, "Sell": 0}}}, "1W": {"Datas": {"Price": {"Initial Price": "58239.43", "Final Price": "58230.02"}, "Oscillators": {"Buy": 1, "Neutral": 9, "Sell": 1}, "MovingAverages": {"Buy": 12, "Neutral": 3, "Sell": 0}}}}

df = pd.json_normalize(js).set_index("Parity")
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split(".")) for c in df.columns], names=["tenor","datas","type","measure"])
df = df.droplevel("datas",1)
```

### sample output

```
tenor                         1m                                                                             5m                                                                 
type                       Price             Oscillators              MovingAverages                      Price             Oscillators              MovingAverages             
measure            Initial Price Final Price         Buy Neutral Sell            Buy Neutral Sell Initial Price Final Price         Buy Neutral Sell            Buy Neutral Sell
Parity                                                                                                                                                                          
BITCOIN / TETHERUS      58239.43    58236.50           1       8    2              6       1    8      58239.43    58231.56           0       9    2             13       1    1
```